# In Geogebra, can you plot the abscissa (xAxis) vertically and the ordinate (yAxis) horizontally?

Tags: geogebra

In GeoGebra, can you plot the abscissa (xAxis) vertically and the ordinate (yAxis) horizontally?

I need this, since I like to visualise an inverse. Since I also like to visualise an Area between different values, I need an IntegralBetween for an interval on y's (so re-interpreting x as y does not work). In addition the function is very tall, so I like to have the layout rotated by 90 degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GeoGebra's 2D view `x` always refers to the horizontal and `y` to the vertical axes. You can however shade the area between two functions in `y` using [inequalities with zero line thickness](https://geogebra.org/classic?command=a:sin(y)%3C=x%3C=sin(y)--1%E2%88%A70%3Cy%3C5;SetLineThickness(a,0))

Comment: It would be OK to have x refer to horizontal and y to vertical, if I could write functions as x = f(y). So the question is: is the independent always horizontal and the dependent always vertical? - I assume your answer is that this is the case. - Your hint to inequalities looks helpful. I will check it out.

Comment: yes, dependent is always vertical. GeoGebra also supports implicit curves (so x=sin(y) is a valid syntax), but those are not quite the same as functions, e.g. you can't use them as argument for Integral. Another thing you can do is reflect a function about the line x=y.